# SQL Server Conditional Count Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to do something apparently simple in sql server but not been able to achieve the desired result yet (I am of course not a sql expert).

My source table:

[image]

And I am trying to get the output like below:

[image]

I have tried to give the field names meaningful so that the problem becomes self explanatory. I haven't been able to generate the 3rd column of the desired output yet.

Please can someone help??

Thanks & Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below -

```
select date,count(*) as idcount,count(case when status='Pass' then 1 end) as idpassed
from tablname
group by date
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Fahmi!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Declare @t table( dates varchar(50),id int,status varchar(50))

insert into @t values ('2019/8',1,'Pass')
insert into @t values ('2019/9',1,'fail')
insert into @t values ('2019/9',2,'fail')
insert into @t values ('2019/8',3,'fail')

select dates,count(id) idcount,sum(case when status='pass' then 1 else 0 end)  as pascount from @t 
group by dates
```